# How to extract characters not supported in unicode?

Tags: python, unicode, apache-tika

I am trying to extract text from a PDF using Tika-App 1.21.
While extraction, it was found that some of the characters in the PDF have no unicode mapping. Is there any way to find the equivalent character in Unicode?

Comment: What language and script are you trying to extract?

Comment: English language Font-K

Comment: Well I can't think of any character used in English that is not encoded in Unicode. Can you attach an image of the character to the question?

Comment: "Font-K"? So it's some font that uses arbitrary glyphs for character points not really intended for them…?

Comment: Well, while I use Apache-Tika on the PDF, i get error messages like WARN  No Unicode mapping for a92 (92) in font K

Comment: I think you need to decode to simple format and extract characters and then encode to unicode format.

Comment: So, how do you suggest doing that? Is there any parser other than Tika, which can give me that functionality?

Comment: Or rather your chosen font does not support the character you try to insert…?

Comment: without images, snippets of the unreadable characters, the code you are using with the calls to Python libraries yu are releasing to get your text back, it is really not possible to help you.